# No output matching file names using split() and glob.glob()

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, glob

I am trying to find all files in a bunch of subdirectories that have either the form:
`sub-num_ses-wavenum_task-name_run-num_info.ext`
 or
`sub-num_ses-wavenum_task-name_info.ext`

The part of the file name `run-num` can take the form `run-01` through `run-15` or higher depending on the number files with matching `task-name` segments. There is not `run-num` if there are no duplicate task names.

The script can successfully enter the directories and I can break the file name into chunks by separating at `_`

```
niidir="some/path"  
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(niidir): 
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname == "fmap" or dirname == "anat" or dirname == "func":
            fullpath = dirpath + "/" + dirname
            for files in fullpath:
                for file in os.listdir(fullpath):
                    chunks = file.split("_")
                        print(chunks)
```

Where `print(chunks)` will give the output:
`['sub-num', 'ses-wavenum', 'task-name', 'run-num', 'info.ext']`
or, if there is no `run-num`:
`['sub-num', 'ses-wavenum', 'task-name', 'info.ext']`

I can also break out the part I want to check to see whether it is a run number or not:

```
niidir="some/path"  
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(niidir): 
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname == "fmap" or dirname == "anat" or dirname == "func":
            fullpath = dirpath + "/" + dirname
            for files in fullpath:
                for file in os.listdir(fullpath):
                    chunks = file.split("_")
                        print(chunks[-2])
```

Returns, e.g.:
`run-02`, if there is a run number, or
`task-name`, if there is no run number.

**BUT**, my problem is that I can't seem to list out *only* those files that have a run number:

```
niidir="some/path"  
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(niidir): 
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname == "fmap" or dirname == "anat" or dirname == "func":
            fullpath = dirpath + "/" + dirname
            for files in fullpath:
                for file in os.listdir(fullpath):
                    chunks = file.split("_")
                    if chunks[-2]) == glob.glob("run-[0-9]{2}"):
                        print(chunks[-2])
```

Gives me no output at all.

I'm at a loss as to why I can't find the matching sting.

**Edit 1:**
path to files is `niidir/sub-num/ses-num/sequence/files`

There are multiple sub-num directories in clean_nii and multiple ses-num directories in each sub-num directory. Each ses-num directory contains some or all of the following sequence directories: "anat", "func", or "fmap" in which are the files.

**Edit 2:** I'm not a programmer. Please don't assume I know what you're talking about, even if it's "basic". I'm trying.

Comment: Globs are not regexs.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: They use different syntaxes. You are using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for the glob, and you are using globbing incorrectly. Your `glob()` call wants to match a literal `{2}` string after a single digit, and you are trying to use a function that produces a list of files to test if a string matches a pattern.

The correct pattern to match your files would be:

```
glob.glob("run-[0-9][0-9]*")
```

Glob patterns are *not regular expressions*. See the [wikipedia article on glob syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), and the [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) for details.

Next, `glob.glob()` looks up files on the filesystem, and returns a *list of matching filenames*. The above pattern has no path information so only lists files in the local working directory. You'd have to use `glob.glob(os.path.join(fullpath, "run-[0-9][0-9]*")` to match specific files in a directory, at which point the list will consist of *full paths*. You should not compare that list with a single string, `chunks[-2]` is **never** going to be equal to a list of matching filenames.

If you want to see if your string matches a specific globbing pattern, you'd use the [`fname.fnmatch()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch):

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(chunks[-2], 'run-[0-9][0-9]'):
```

Now you are actually testing if your filename part consists of the string `run-` at the start, followed by two digits.

Next, your `for files in fullpath` loop iterates over *individual characters* of the `fullpath` string. You are repeating this loop `len(filepath)` times, without any need to repeat anything. You ignore the `files` variable, you are just doing needless extra work.

Next, your code is still doing more work than it needs to. `os.walk()` will *already* list filenames in directories, yet your code lists them redundantly with a `os.listdir()` call. Either prune your `dirnames` list after you found those specific subdirectories, or test `dirpath` for a matching subdirectory and process `files` instead:

```
import os
import os.path
import fnmatch

niidir="some/path" 

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(niidir): 
    directory_name = os.path.basename(dirpath)
    if directory not in {'fmap', 'anat', 'func'}:
        # Only process files in specific subdirectories
        continue
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, "run-[0-9][0-9]*"):
        # process matching file
```

I used the [`fnmatch.filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) to filter out matching names from the `files` list produced by `os.walk()`.

Alternatively, stick to `fnmatch.fnmatch()` if you want to process all files in the directory and only test specific files in the larger list for your pattern:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(niidir): 
    directory_name = os.path.basename(dirpath)
    if directory not in {'fmap', 'anat', 'func'}:
        # Only process files in specific subdirectories
        continue
    for filename in files:
        prefix, remainder = filename.partition('_')
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(prefix, 'run-[0-9][0-9]'):
            # filename starts with a run-number.
        else:
            # do something else
```

Comment: Thank you, however `glob.glob("run-[0-9][0-9]*"):` also does not return anything.

Comment: @kdestasio: no, because it has no full path. You should not be using it anyway.

Comment: @kdestasio: I think I covered everything that was wrong in your code, which was quite a few things. `glob.glob()` is entirely the wrong thing to use here.